# Entity Framework Core, relational columns and data retrieval

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am using SQL Server. In my API I have this class for `DbContext` and I am generating tables through code-first approach.

And this are my two classes that have PK-FK relationship.

```
class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Bookings
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    //Some other properties
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }  
}
```

As I've read from somewhere, that object of some class inside another one is enough to tell the Entity Framework Core that this is foreign key.

Now I generated the migration, and update the database which will create foreign key of customer in my booking table and everything works fine.

But when you retrieve the `Booking` object(s) from the `Booking` table, the foreign key is integer which can not be stored in my object property of type `Customer`. So my retrieved object(s) will get all the value but the `Customer` object will remain null.

So what is the solution for this in Entity Framework Core that I can retrieve `CustomerId` in my object without making changes to database?

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely missing the `.Include` method when using the database context. You should do something like the following:

```
var values = await _context.Bookings
                           .Include(x => x.Customer)
                           .ToListAsync();
```

This will tell Entity Framework Core to eagerly load the `Customer` object, when retrieving bookings. For more information about loading related data, you can check [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).

Comment: I'm still learning ef core code first and thanks i didn't know about this method. Instead i was using extra column property with same name as foreign key which will automap my foreign key data in that column property.  (Just a property without adding a column to database).. i would like to know if that is a valid solution for this problem.

Comment: I don't see any problem with modelling like you did. As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties), Entity Framework Core will detect that no foreign key property was specified in your model, and therefore will create a shadow property.

The `.Include` method ensures the `Customer` object is retrieved/populated when loading the `Booking` object.